# How to remove an in-between merge in git?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase, git-merge, git-reset

I want to remove an in-between merge (remove, not squash) and then move the last 2 commits to a new branch.

This is my current `git log --graph`:

```
* 3a5c453 - (2 hours ago) last commit (HEAD, master)
*   b6c19f1 - (2 hours ago) Merge branch 'tade' into HEAD
|\  
* | be356d0 - (2 hours ago) previous commit
| * 65328dc - (3 hours ago) some other commit in branch tade
```

I want to end up with this:

```
    * bbbbbbb - (some time in the future) a later commit on tade (tade)
*   | aaaaaaa - (some time in the future) a later commit on master (master)
| * | 3a5c453 - (2 hours ago) last commit (HEAD, newone)
| * | be356d0 - (2 hours ago) previous commit
|/  |
|   * 65328dc - (3 hours ago) some other commit in branch tade
```

I thought of using `git rebase -i` to remove the merge with the branch tade and then do a `git branch newone` and `git reset --hard HEAD^2` to move the last 2 commits to the new branch. When I did the rebase though, it showed me all the commits from the tade branch that got merged into master and | was reluctant in deleting them.

Is there a better way or should I go ahead with it?

EDIT: I updated the intended state graph to make it more clear. The 2 new commit (`aaaaaaa` and `bbbbbbb`) are only there to illustrate the state a little better (I hope)

Comment: I'm really confused by those vertical lines in your desired result. Is there some other commit up above there, on branch tade, and on... whatever implied branch is at the far left?

Comment: It'd also be helpful if you labeled your current HEAD with an actual branch name, and told us how exactly you invoked `rebase -i`.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to the git log --graph output. I will change the graph to clarify the intended state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interactive rebasing to rebase `3a5c453` on `be356d0` instead of the merge commit `b6c19f1` (i.e. just move the `3a5c453` commit one down). Then you should have something like this:

```
*   xxxxxxx - (2 hours ago) Merge branch 'tade' into HEAD
|\  
* | yyyyyyy - (2 hours ago) last commit (HEAD)
* | be356d0 - (2 hours ago) previous commit
| * 65328dc - (3 hours ago) some other commit in branch tade
```

Then you can just create new branches:

```
git checkout -b newbranch yyyyyy
```

Then you can delete `xxxxxx` and commit something to the master and end up with this:

```
* zzzzzz - new commit on master
| * | yyyyyyy - (2 hours ago) last commit (HEAD)
| * | be356d0 - (2 hours ago) previous commit
| | * 65328dc - (3 hours ago) some other commit in branch tade
```

Comment: When I do the interactive rebase, I get a ton of commits (from the tade branch) in-between my 2 commits. Should I just move all of them below?

Comment: Try `rebase -i 65328dc` and it should only give those between `65328dc` and the current HEAD.